# Create a menu growing from bottom

Tags: css, reactjs, menu

This is what I'm trying to reproduce using React:

[image]

It' a simple menu that grows from bottom.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/menu-growing-from-bottom-d76cj?file=/src/App.js) is my code.

I animate `max-height` property instead of `height` and my logic was to create a parent div whose contains the open menu (composed by About, works, contact and read it) and the close menu (so the actual open section. About for example).
The close menu should be over the open menu if it is closed, and below if it open.

If you test my code you should note some problems:

1. there is something that doesn't work with over because it's not easy to click on a row
2. the bottom label is always "About".

How can I fix it?